# Comments with bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, comments

I got stuck. I'm developing a website now with bootstrap and wordpress, and there my comments form looks like that:

http://video-walks.ru.com/?p=408

As you can see the words positioned under the inputs not above as it must be and the fields are too short. I'm newbie and would like to get some help from you guys. 
This is my simple code in single.php:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><em><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></em></p>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <hr>
        <?php comments_template('',true); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="pager"> <li class="previous"> <?php previous_post_link('%link', '&laquo; Предыдущая запись',TRUE); ?> </li>
 <li class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Следующая запись &raquo;', TRUE); ?> </li> </ul> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found some solution, added comments.php from other theme  and some code to functions.php. Thanks!